# myLocationEnabled - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I'm simply trying to get the users location in my MapViewController using the GoogleMaps API.
I've looked around everywhere and can't figure out why I am continually getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping and Optional value in this particular place.

Here is my code:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-34.9290, longitude:138.6010, zoom:10)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)
        mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        print("Calling addMarker")
        // addMarker()
        self.view = mapView
        }

extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am getting the error:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKUd7.jpg)

I get that `mapView.myLocationEnabled` is returning nil but don't understand why/how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is mapView that is nil, not mapView.myLocationEnabled. When you get that crash try the following lldb command:

```
po mapView
```

and that will tell you exactly.

The didChangeAuthorizationStatus delegate is probably being called from the background or before the view is complete. You should move those extensions into your AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed you were right, po mapView shows that mapView is an unresolved identifier. However moving the extensions into AppDelegate did not fix the error :(

Comment: Is the IBOutlet connected to the corresponding view in Interface Builder?